# “feel tired” vs. “am tired”

Tags: word-choice, grammar, differences, word-usage, sense-verbs

Which of these two sentences is more appropriate in a given situation?

> I am tired.
>
> I am feeling tired.

I know this might be a very childish question, but English is not my first language and I just want to know more about authentic English.

Comment: there is a great site http://ell.stackexchange.com - To me, the am tired is more tired than feeling tired. As in _I am tired I will go to bed_ vs _I am feeling tired, I will have a cup of coffee_

Comment: NOAD defines _feel_ several ways; one of them is: **consider oneself to be in a particular state or exhibiting particular qualities**. So, if you _feel_ grouchy, then you pretty much _are_ grouchy; if you _feel_ elated, that's pretty much the same as _being_ elated. Same goes for _tired_, in my mind. Of course, there are other meanings of _feel_, too, such as: **have a belief or impression, esp. without an identifiable reason**, so, in some contexts, there may be more of a distinct nuance, as when a worker says, "I feel more tired than usual for some reason" – _feel_ might be better than _am_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me put it this way:

> He is feeling dead. Means he is not *dead*, but is feeling like it.
>
> He is dead. Means he is dead. Period.

*Feeling tired* means you are feeling like tired or tiredness is slowing taking over you. In the other example you are tired and don't want to give further explanation. There's nothing more to it:)

Comment: While the difference is very significant for _is dead_ vs _feeling dead_, I don't think the difference is as pronounced for _is tired_ vs _feeling tired_. If I announce that I'm "feeling tired," chances are that I _am_ tired.

Comment: @J.R. Right. I was just trying to illustrate how the two could change the meaning of an entire sentence. I agree with your observation but that can only be true when you are not really picky. A: I am feeling tired. B: Are you feeling tired or are you tired? A: Well, I am tired.

Comment: It's hard to feel tired without being tired, but I agree that you can feel dead without being dead, or feel broke (financially) even when you're not literally broke.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is the sense of immediacy the terms provide, in the case of "I feel..." the speaker is distancing themselves from the situation, allowing themselves room to be ambiguous.  In a sense not committing fully to the statement.  In the case of "I am..." the speaker is stepping into the immediate sensation, and declaring clearly what IS.

http://tcbdevito.blogspot.com/2011/11/communication-strategies-immediacy.html

Answer (score 0):

Feel tired means that you are not tired in real but you think that you are tired whereas am tired means that you are really tired.